# Is WP Importer Safe on Multisite?

Tags: multisite, import

Is it safe to allow users of a multisite to use WP importer? I'm assuming importer can only create pages, posts and users (if I allow them to add users to their site), but my concern is whether a hacker can create an account and import malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

WP Importer is fine, providing the security of the site is in tact - meaning:

- No users with "admin" username
- secure passwords
- user registration disabled
- Salts configured properly in wp-config.php
- Renowned plugins **ONLY** - lots of plugins can be the cause of a weak link in a sites security, especially if the plugin provides any form of public uploading (in forms, using old versions of Timthumb, etc.)

If a hacker creates and account and imports malicious code, it's the issue of the being insecure, not WP Importer detecting whether a User is a hacker or not.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Eric. User registration is enabled, since the whole purpose is that people can sign up and create a blog (ie, user.mymultisite.com). My inquiry is not whether WP Importer can detect a hacker but, rather, whether it can be used by a hacker. I'll just assume it can be, and not allow site owners to use it.

Comment: I believe WP Importer requires a certain level of capability for user. Most likely a "manage_posts" capability, which Subscribers (generic default user signup level) do not have.

Comment: Actually, it would be the [Import](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#import) capability, which only Admins and Super-Admins have.

Comment: Admin is the concern, as anybody signing up would automatically have their own blog (subdomain) and thus, be an administrator for that blog.

Comment: I won't be allowing use of WP Import for security reasons. Thanks again for the valuable input. :)